# SonarQube plugin - users access management

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to develop a custom plugin restricting access to certain parts of SonarQube (Deletion of project, Modification of permissions etc) depending on their assignment to different groups. 
I was able to implement a filter which will redirect a user in case he tries to access page which is restricted to him.
There are 2 problems I am facing.

- I am not able to get the logged in user (I am able to get his ID via request session but I am not able to get any more information about him.).
- I am not able to get information about groups the user belongs to.

There might be an api for this however I am not able to find any examples or the documentation that might help me.

- SonarQube version: 5.6.6
- Security Realm: Crowd

Thank you,

Jakub

Comment: What is your exact use case ? What is missing in SonarQube in order to reach it ?

Comment: The use case is following. I want to allow only users in specific group (sonar-administrators) to be able to create or delete projects. The creation of the project may be limited by the global permissions but the deletion can be done directly by project administrator.

When going to the Deletion page of SonarQube it should check if the user is in group sonar-administrators and if not redirect him elsewhere. The redirection is implemented but I cannot find any API components to check the said user's groups.

Comment: Why not using user permission instead of groups permission in this case ?

Comment: Because only members of sonar-administrators group (or users which can create projects which is basically the same set of users) should be allowed to delete projects (legal stuff). In any case I was not able to find any API component which would give me info about users' permissions or their groups.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not possible to customize pages access of SonarQube.